# Is it possible to initialize a feed forward backpropagation network in Python Scikit-learn similar to MATLAB's ffnew?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

In MATLAB I noticed that you can initialize a new feed forward backpropagation network just by specifying some parameters of the network (like number of neurons in each layer) without the use of any training data. But using **MLPClassifier** in **sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron**, I find that its is possible to do using only **fit(*train_data, train_label*)**. Is it possible to just initialize a model (which contains correct number of neurons per layer as required) similar to the above mentioned matlab command which doesn't require any training data? Please let me know if my concept is wrong and this question doesn't make sense since I am new to neural networks. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The question is: what for? sklearn's design is not that compatible for this (as the internals are naturally inferred from the input-data). Of course you can easily change the sources to create the network without feeding in data, but well... Other, more advanced libraries (specialized for NNs) will compile some network without seeing any data. Look at Keras, Tensorflow or any other popular lib.

Comment: I wan't  to perform a multi-label classification. At this moment I need to stick to sklearn. But if this cannot be solved, I will look for the other advanced libraries. I heard that pybrain is good. Would you recommend that? It is very important that the library works with numpy arrays.

Comment: Every good python-based lib will on the outside work with numpy-arrays (or scipy sparse matrices) (internally things will change). Of course you can do multi-label classification with sklearns MLP. I don't see the point of your question then. The other libs are much more advanced than sklearn's MLP (so if you need more features, speed and co...). pybrain is dead i think (or at least is not as actively developed than the others; it's also not a pure NN-based lib). And please clean-up your tags. It seems you wanted to include everything which is hardly connected. Especially backprop.

Comment: look into keras

Comment: OK. Thanks @sascha . I removed it. Actually I am re-writing a matlab code to python. So as long as it is possible, I am trying to maintain the same flow as it is in the matlab code (The code can be found here http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/files/BPMLL.rar . I am concerned about line 87 of BPMLL_train.m)

Comment: Keeping the flow is the wrong approach. Different libs will behave differently. It's much more wise to understand the concept and implement this according to the lib. (private opinion: python offers much more high-quality software for NNs than matlab)

Comment: I just skimmed the relevant paper. If their loss is not available in sklearn, which i think, you can't use it. With keras and tensorflow everything is possible, but it will be a lot of work

Comment: I just looked into keras. Seems like its amazing. thanks for the recommendation and your opinions @Julius and sascha

Comment: Actually the loss is not a big problem for me. I am more concerned with net.LW in the code which is defined in the documentation as "  This property defines the weight matrices of weights going to layers
  from other layers. It is always an Nl x Nl cell array, where Nl is the
  number of network layers (net.numLayers).
"
I do not understand what is that and cannot find something similar in sklearn

Comment: @SoumyaShubhraGhosh I begin to think that you will have a hard time porting that code :-/. If the loss (i did not check it) is not within sklearn, then you can't use that lib. At least not without changing the sources. I don't think it does automatic diff and so has some custom-losses to choose (again: my assumptions). Your problem is the most simple at all. Look at the definition of a multilayer-perceptron. What's unclear? In your case (again: **sklearn is the wrong library!**): using e.g. 3 layers of node-size 100 is achieved with ```hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, 100)```